# Source files in src_managed are not part of project sources in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm not very skilled in SBT, may be i'm missing smth

I have bash script that generates some scala sources. I want to use them in my sbt project. I thought that putting them under `target/src_managed/main` directory would work, but it doesn't

In sbt shell i type `sourceDirectories`

```
sbt:root> model/sourceDirectories
[info] * /media/alex/kondaurov_hd/back/model/src/main/scala-2.12
[info] * /media/alex/kondaurov_hd/back/model/src/main/scala
[info] * /media/alex/kondaurov_hd/back/model/src/main/java
[info] * /media/alex/kondaurov_hd/back/model/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main
```

src_managed should be available, no?

```
sbt:root> show model/sources
[info] * /media/alex/kondaurov_hd/back/model/src/main/scala/model/ModelUtils.scala
[info] * /media/alex/kondaurov_hd/back/model/src/main/scala/model/implicits/Response.scala
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Nov 25, 2018 1:44:02 PM
```

I don't seed sources under src_managed directory.

Answer (score 2):

> "I thought that putting them under target/src_managed/main directory would work, but it doesn't".

Well, it does not work, because as the name says, they are *sources* **managed** by SBT - that means SBT must know about them and be in the capacity of generate them.
Thus, you have two options:

1. **Make them *unmanaged sources***
    That basically means make your script to create the sources in `src/main/scala/some/package/GeneratedFile.scala` - this is the simplest solution, but it has its owns problems.

   - The generated files become part of the code repository - but since they are generated they aren't intended to be modified *perse*.
   - You need to ensure that before each package/release/deploy the script is run.
2. **Configure SBT to create the *managed sources* from your script**
    You can have a look at the [sbt ***documentation***](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html) about source generators - and the [***documentation***](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Process.html) about running external processes for help for running the bash script inside SBT.
    You basically have to create an SBT task that creates the files - this may be more difficult at the beginning but it has the advantage that sbt will take care of generating the sources every time they are needed.
     You may find this [simple demo](https://github.com/BalmungSan/fastpath-demo) I made a few months ago as a reference for creating your own generator - the import code is in the `build.sbt` file.
     For a more production ready version of the generator, including appropriate location, dependency segregation and testing you may take a look at [this](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala/tree/master/project).

Comment: I was thinking about option #2. The idea is to write a source generator that just reads files that were generated by external bash script (like a proxy). Thanks for help!

Comment: Yeah that can work, the ideal scenario is that the generator calls the bash script to generate the files, and then return the list of generated files to be managed.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found answer, now it works:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value.getParentFile.getParentFile / "protos" / "generated" / "scala"
```